# Exponential submartingale inequality

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

In a [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/SAP-100001183) I am reading I found the following:

"Applying the exponential martingale inequality we derive that
$$P\Big(\omega: \sup_{0 \leq t \leq k}[M(t)-1/2 \epsilon \langle M(t) \rangle] \leq 2 \epsilon^{-1} \log k \Big) \leq k^{-2}. \quad (1) "$$
$\epsilon$ and $k$ are positive constants.

My thoughts:

$\{M(t)\}$ is a continuous martingale that vanishes at $t=0,$ so the process $\{M(t)-1/2 \epsilon \langle M(t) \rangle\}$ is a submartingale. The inequality (1) looks like a version of Doob's submartingale inequality but I haven't been able to link it.

Does anybody knows where inequality (1) comes from? I appreciate any idea or reference that can throw some light on it.

Comment: For context: can you link the paper in which you found this inequality?

Comment: @JoseAvilez. It's this paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/SAP-100001183  (But I can't find a "free" link to the paper. I got it by email)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under some mild regularity conditions, the stochastic exponential process $$X_t = \mathcal{E}(\epsilon M)_t = \exp\left( \epsilon M_t - \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 \langle M \rangle_t \right)$$
is a non-negative martingale martingale starting at $X_0 = 1$; in such a case $E(X_t) = 1$ for all $t \geq 0$.
Then,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{0 \leq t \leq k} \left( M_t - \frac{1}{2} \epsilon \langle M \rangle_t \right)\geq 2 \epsilon^{-1} \log k \right)
 &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{0 \leq t \leq k} \exp \left( \epsilon M_t - \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 \langle M \rangle_t  \right) \geq k^2 \right) \\
&\leq \frac{E(X_k^+)}{k^2} \\
&=  \frac{E(X_k)}{k^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2}
\end{align*}$$
where the inequality is Doob's martingale inequality applied to $X_t$.

Comment: Thank you!  Jose Avilez